# Select count(*) from result query

Tags: sql, sql-server, select

I need help from you, this is my sql query:

```
select count(SID) 
from Test 
where Date = '2012-12-10' 
group by SID
```

this is my result:

```
|2|
|3|
|4|
|3|
```

and now I have to count the results from first query!

```
Expected result: 4
```

Comment: Are there any columns in your table? You want to count SID group by SID? hmm.... +1 to @bluefeet I too guess it's max count of (SID) for that date... but guess his comment is gone..

Comment: I have to count the rows! count(2,3,4,3)

Answer (score 95, accepted):

You can wrap your query in another `SELECT`:

```
select count(*)
from
(
  select count(SID) tot  -- add alias
  from Test 
  where Date = '2012-12-10' 
  group by SID
) src;  -- add alias
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/679e9/9)

In order for it to work, the `count(SID)` need a column alias and you have to provide an alias to the subquery itself.

Comment: Can anyone explain why you need the aliases? I tried it without them and it didn't work, but it's not obvious to me that you need them considering you never use them ('tot' and 'src' in this case) in the query.

Comment: @GarrettDisco Since you are using a subquery, each column in the subquery needs to have a name aka an alias. SQL Server also requires an alias on subqueries.

Answer (score 9):

This counts the rows of the inner query:

```
select count(*) from (
    select count(SID) 
    from Test 
    where Date = '2012-12-10' 
    group by SID
) t
```

However, in this case the effect of that is the same as this:

```
select count(distinct SID) from Test where Date = '2012-12-10'
```

Comment: @SigiAnonym, I don't have SQL Server to test. But does the updated version work?

Comment: @dan1111 try SQLFIDDLE ;) on the web.

Comment: do i need to add the colums at the end of the command and the alias ?

Answer (score 1):

`select count(*) from(select count(SID) from Test where Date = '2012-12-10' group by SID)`select count(*) from(select count(SID) from Test where Date = '2012-12-10' group by SID)

should works